# Lot's Daughters

Tags: history, historical-figures, sexuality, family-members, vayera

Why did Lot's daughters have relations with their father?

Comment: Do you have some reason to suspect they shouldn't have?

Comment: @DoubleAA Don't expect an answer anytime soon -- this account is unregistered, and hasn't been active since 2011 :P [ *presumably, the reason to assume they shouldn't is because it is forbidden, and generally considered to be weird* ]

Comment: 19:31 seems clear enough. Why is this a question?  (There may be *other* reasons, of course, but it's not as if the text is silent on the subject.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. They thought there was no one left in the World (**ibn Ezra** and
   **ibn Kaspi**, **Rashi** and **Rashbam**)
2. **Radak** says they thought no one would marry them since they came from the destroyed cities they would be outcasts
3. **Seforno** has the most intriguing answer -- they held themselves to have a great Yichus and there was no one good enough left to marry.